# Proof of period of $\cos^{n}(ax+b)$ ((Update))

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

We know that period of $\cos(ax+b)$ assuming $a\neq0$ is $T=\frac{2\pi}{a}$ my question is why is it that $\cos^{n}(ax+b)$assuming $a\neq0$ has a period of $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{a}$ if $n$ is odd and $\displaystyle\frac{2\pi}{a}$ if $n$ is even?

Update:

Well it seems we can express the powers of sine in terms of a binomial expansion:
$$
\sin^{2m}(x)~=~\frac{(-1)^m}{2^n}\left[2^*\sum_{k=0}^m~\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\cos((n-2k)x)\right]
$$
$$
\sin^{2m+1}(x)~=~\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{n-1}}\left[\sum_{k=0}^m~\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\sin((n-2k)x)\right]
$$

Comment: Start with just $n=2$. Do you know the period of $\cos^2(ax+b)$?

Comment: So we have $\frac{4\pi^{2}}{a^{2}}$ right? @ndhanson3

Comment: You don't find the period by simply squaring the period of $\cos(ax+b)$. Perhaps graph $\cos(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$. You'll find eventually that the period of $\cos^2(ax+b)$ is $\frac{\pi}{a}$.

Comment: I thought of induction for a moment. I wasn't aware that we can not square the period :(

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2t = \frac{1+\cos 2t}2$

Comment: $\cos (u+\pi) = -\cos u.$  Which implies $\cos^2 u$ has period $\pi.$  Letting $u = ax$ we can conclude $\cos^2 u$ has period $\frac {\pi}{a}.$   Alternatively, we could say $\cos^2 u = \frac 12 (\cos 2u + 1)$ to arrive at the same conclusion.

Comment: Oh yes, this means $T_{2}=\frac{2\pi}{2}=\pi$. Indeed, for $\cos^{2}(at+b)=\frac{1+\cos(2at+2b)}{2}$ yields a period of $\frac{\pi}{a}$. Now do we use higher order trignomentric relations?

Comment: But we are reaching a conclusion for one even natural number. If we were to replace $2n$ do we establish a trigonometric relation for this general case?

Comment: Would taylor series help?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen any idea if it would be applicable to use Taylor series or exponential representation?